# Performance characteristics of a wireless symmetric internet connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet

I'm exploring the possibility of obtaining an internet connection in an area not serviced by high speed cables. The upload speeds are always very slow on cable. I have found a wireless service (aka Wimax) that is "symmetric" (for a price). There is a transmitter within 1.5 km of the house. I would like to use this but my concern is that radio cannot actually provide the advantages of symmetric over a fixed line.

From my research, I understand that symmetric internet connections support simultaneous download and upload operations without competing with each other. I could use this for video conferencing, screen sharing, cloud file sync, etc.

So, my question is: what are the characteristics of a symmetric internet connection over radio? Are they the same as a fixed line? Are there any caveats?

Comment: I see you got an [answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/50305) here.

Comment: Actual Wimax? Not Wi-Fi with airMAX?

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Comment: The question was "off-topic" on the other site, which is why it's here. Apparently someone answered before it was put on hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike 802.11, WiMax (802.16) is Full duplex. Which means it can send and receive simultaneously. (Symmetrical up/down) is achievable in proper installations.

This is why it's a selling point, if it was provided over a 802.11 connection, it could send or receive but not simultaneously.

WiMax also has support built into the standard to support many more clients than 802.11. and better throughput vs distance.

The only caveats I'm aware of are on the service provider side. If you want a carrier grade service offered, you pretty much have to use the licensed bands to avoid interference issues in the unlicensed bands. Additionally as with all radio links. There is more latency involved than with a direct line link, but in some installations can out perform DSL service average latency.

As far as actual throughput, you should receive the bandwidth you are paying for, as long as your provider is not over subscribing on the access towers.

Comment: Excellent answer. Pretty sure it's WiMax and over a dedicated line. In any case, I'll have the signal tested before purchasing. On that note, any thoughts on the 1.5 km range (with a clear line-of-sight)? I'm concerned it's too far for ongoing stability -- e.g. considering atmospheric conditions, etc.

Comment: t can be transmitted up to 40 miles with speeds close to 70 Mbps. I would assume they are using a licenced band, which means at 1.5km, it should be very reliable.